# Oracle Data Guard:Can archived redo log files be sent from primary database to physical standby database manually?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dataguard

As a result of the configuration of firewall,the primary database can`t not send the archived redo log to physical standby database in real time,the network connection between primary and physical standby would be available at midnight.In that case,i want to copy the archive log to physical standby manually by the shell scripts.In the general case,the sending of archived redo log is handled by the process call ARCH,so if i copy the archived the redo log to the physical standby ,can the data guard keep working correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can manually script it.

This is covered in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/log_transport.htm#SBYDB4759).

In essence, you copy the archive log files to the correct filesystem location on the logical standby host, then register them using the `ALTER DATABASE REGISTER LOGFILE` command.